# How unique is $e$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, exponential-function

Is the property of a function being its own derivative unique to $e^x$, or are there other functions with this property? My working for $e$ is that for any $y=a^x$, $ln(y)=x\ln a$, so $\frac{dy}{dx}=\ln(a)a^x$, which equals $a^x$ if and only if $a=e$.

Considering equations of different forms, for example $y=mx+c$ we get $\frac{dy}{dx}=m$ and $mx+c=m$ only when $m=0$ and $c=0$, so there is not solution other than $y=0$. For $y=x^a$, $\frac{dy}{dx}=ax^{a-1}$, which I think equals $x^a$ only when $a=x$ and therefore no solutions for a constant a exist other than the trivial $y=0$.

Is this property unique to equations of the form $y=a^x$, or do there exist other cases where it is true? I think this is possibly a question that could be answered through differential equations, although I am unfortunately not familiar with them yet!

Comment: probably as unique as every other real number.

Comment: Yes $e^x$ is the only function that is its own derivative.

Comment: @acernine Use the product rule on $ye^{-x}$ and you'll see that if $y'=y$ then the derivative of $ye^{-x}$ is $0$, making it constant, so $y$ must take the form $Ce^x$.

Comment: @Gregory Grant With $x \mapsto 0$ :)

Comment: @ErickWong I see it now, thank you :) Also shows why this is the case for 0 (0*e^x), so kills two birds with one stone!

Comment: @GregoryGrant, well except for $ae^x$ :)

Comment: @PaxKivimae good point

Comment: For all constant $c $ and *only* for constant cs then $ce^x $ is its derivative.  It's unique to a scalar constant.

Comment: @GregoryGrant, or $f(x)=0$.

Comment: @user1717828 That's included in $ce^x$.

Comment: See this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1292586/72031 which says that $f'(x) = f(x), f(0) = 1$ completely characterizes the exponential function $\exp(x)$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764187/is-the-natural-logarithm-actually-unique-as-a-multiplier

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Assume that $f(x)$ is a function such that $f'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$. Consider the quotient $g(x)=f(x)/e^x$. We can differentiate
$$
g'(x)=\frac{f'(x)e^x-f(x)D e^x}{(e^x)^2}=\frac{f(x)e^x-f(x)e^x}{(e^x)^2}=0.
$$
By the mean value theorem it follows that $g(x)$ is a constant. QED.

Comment: The same idea as in Jason's answer but without differential equations.

Answer (score 10):

Consider the equation $y'=y$.  Our goal is to solve for the function $y=f(x)$.  Roughly speaking $$\frac{dy}{dx}=y \implies \frac{dy}{y}=dx \implies \int\frac{dy}{y}=\int dx \implies\ln(y)=x+C \implies y=e^{x+C}=Ae^x$$

for some constant $A$

Comment: You have to figure out what $\frac d{dx}\ln(y)$ means first, to do that.  Which usually requires knowing $\frac d{dx}e^x=e^x$.  Big circle of going nowhere.

Comment: @SimpleArt I dont think so, since its not a question of existence of $e^x$, but rather uniqueness.

Comment: @SimpleArt This is a slightly different fact.

Comment: This is standard, but the OP confesses unfamiliarity with differential equations and there is a bit of untidiness here in dealing with the $y=0$ and $y<0$ cases.

Comment: @ErickWong Ah, unfortunately I only skimmed the question so I didn't see that last part.  Yes, I agree the $y \leq 0$ cases are untidy, but if one wants a general understanding, I think this argument suffices, even if one is unfamiliar with differential equations.  I'll add some comments to explain.

Comment: The new argument relies on an assumption that $f$ is analytic. Is there a simple way to prove that without first proving that $f(x) = Ae^x$?

Comment: @user2357112 Does $f'=f$ not imply analyticity?

Comment: @JasonM: I'm not seeing any obvious way it does, aside from going through $f(x) = Ae^x$.

Comment: @user2357112 Ok, I'll remove it

Answer (score 4):

This may not be an answer you are looking for, but its a nice one to consider.

Consider $y=\cos(ix)-i\sin(ix)$.

You may find that:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-i\sin(ix)-i^2\cos(ix)=\cos(ix)-i\sin(ix)$$

Thus, $y'=y$ is satisfied.  Since $y(0)=1$, $y'(0)=1$, $\dots$, then by Taylor's theorem, we have $e^x=\cos(ix)-i\sin(ix)$, or more commonly known as

$$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$

Which is Euler's formula for complex exponents.

Comment: This shows that $e^x$ is _a_ solution, not that it is a unique solution.

Comment: @Aditya Not really meant to be an answer in the first place, more of an interesting fact.

Answer (score 4):

The equation
$$
  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} f(x) = f(x)
$$
is a linear (thus [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity)), first-order [ordinary differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation) on $\mathbb{R}$. By the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem), such an equation has a unique solution for any initial condition of the form
$$
  f(0) = y_0
$$
with $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. In particular, for the condition
$$
  f(0) = 1
$$
the unique solution is $f = \exp$, so given that condition, $e \equiv \exp(1) = f(1)$ is unique.

For the general initial condition, you get, because the ODE is [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity), that the solution is always
$$
  f(x) = y_0 \cdot \exp(x).
$$